# Validation inclusions_of accept strings as false values

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I'm creating some models using MonogID and one of them is a boolean value that can accept nil values. Here is how I defined the model.

```
class Status
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :pending, type: Boolean
  validates :pending, inclusion: { in: [true, false], allow_nil: true }
  #...
end
```

As you can see I set the accepted values as booleans and nil. The problem is that when I assign a string, it is transformed to false and accepted. In this way the validation does not work. The second test in this case just fails.

```
it { [true, false, nil].each { |value| should allow_value(value).for(:pending) } }
it { ['not_valid', ''].each { |value| should_not allow_value(value).for(:pending) } }
```

Now, the only solution I'm coming out with is to make a custom validator that check out for the value being a TrueClass, FalseClass or NilClass, but it seems I'm loosing an easier solution. I've checked around the web, but I didn't find out a solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't able to find the solution because when you assign a value to Boolean field it interprets that value as true, false or nil and when you try to save it will have value one out of this (true, false, nil) which will pass the validation.

Comment: I finally got it. Still I was curious to know about possible solutions.

Comment: Right now I accept the fact that any string different from "true" is taken as a false value. But I guess, for now, the real solution is to make a validator that check the class you get.

Comment: but you'll always get these three classes in this field TrueClass, FalseClass and NilClass then what is the need of validation for inclusion if you don't get any other value from this. I am just trying to understand.

Comment: I expect people can make mistakes. Actually they could send a string, and instead of silently set 'false' as value, I would like to give them an error message. I think silent errors are just bad.

Comment: but by validation we can't make that judgement. Because when a string will be assigned to boolean field it will interpret it in either of these three true, false and nil. And while checking validation it can't be checked. And if you have got the solution otherwise please share with me.